# Using cy.tick() together with rxjs auditTime

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, cypress, ngrx

We have an e2e test for a feature that uses ngrx state management. The feature collects user inputs over 60 seconds via the `auditTime()` operator and posts them to an API endpoint.

Since I don't want to wait for 60 seconds each run, I was thinking of using the `cy.tick(58000)` function to skip time forward. However, it appears that time is not skipped at all.

```
it('should send a http post request after 60 seconds', () => {
        cy.intercept('POST', '**/my-page').as('my-post'); // intercept the post
        cy.clock(); // instantiate clock object
        cy.visit('/home'); // visit page

        // some inputs here
        cy.tick(58000); // skip 58 seconds

        // this wait command times out
        cy.wait('@my-post', { timeout: 15000 }).then((interception: any) => {
            const statusCode = interception.response.statusCode;
            expect(statusCode).equal(200);
       });
});
```

The observable itself that uses the auditTime operator is created within an ngrx effect:

```
postObservable$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.store.select(FromData.selectData).pipe(
        auditTime(60_000), // important part
        filter((data) => data.length > 0),
        map((result) => [
            ...result.map((dataElement) =>
                toDataDTO({
                    dataId: dataElement.postId,
                    createdAt: dataElement.createdAt,
                })
            ),
        ]),
    ...
});
```

Each time, the test times out after 15 seconds. It works if I reduce the `auditTime()` period to one second or similar.

How can I make sure Cypress ticks work for rxjs operators such as `auditTime()`?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make a mock of the time parameter.

```js
const timeParam = window.Cypress ? 300 : 60_000;

postObservable$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.store.select(FromData.selectData).pipe(

        auditTime(timeParam), 

        filter((data) => data.length > 0),
        map((result) => [
            ...result.map((dataElement) =>
                toDataDTO({
                    dataId: dataElement.postId,
                    createdAt: dataElement.createdAt,
                })
            ),
        ]),
    ...
})
```

Maybe that breaks the logic of the app (e.g race condition with another Rx feed).

---

Since clock() controls `Date`, `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`, I had a quick look to see if any of these underly the timing of `auditTime()`. There is [TimestampProvider](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/888c753e272443bbb879f9ffb1a8145a7773c865/src/internal/scheduler/dateTimestampProvider.ts) that uses `Date.now()` but can't tell how to mock that effectively.

Alternatively, [TestScheduler](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/d279670a7e43eb140710596beda67351fffd529f/spec/operators/auditTime-spec.ts) may provide a way to accelerate the interval, but I can't see how to use it in an e2e test.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to keep test code separate from application code. I will try to create a reproducible example tonight. There is a similar issue on GIthub, too: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/24227

Comment: That issue seems different - the store dispatch is wrapped in a setTimeout() which is (supposed to be) patched by Cypress and thus controlled by cy.clock() and cy.tick(). But your code is using auditTime() which ultimately uses a scheduler.